# Recursion in java, which one could be the best?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class a1 {

    private static int unit = 0;

    private static int sum = 0;

    public static void main(String[] foo) {
        unit = 10;
        System.out.println(tailRecur(unit));

        System.out.println(tailRecur2(10));
    }

    public static int tailRecur(int result) {
        int sum = result + unit - 1;
        unit = unit - 1;
        if (unit == 0) {
            return sum;
        }
        return tailRecur(sum);
    }

    public static int tailRecur2(int unit) {
        if (unit == 0) return sum;
        sum = sum + unit;
        return tailRecur2(unit - 1);
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple method to get achieve 1+...+10. I am not sure which one could be better with the meaning of recursion syntax. The all give me the right answer.

Comment: The function calls itself, that's the only definition of recursion, so this seems to be an opinion based question

Comment: I would say that neither are correct. They shouldn't be using a static field.

Comment: Also, neither are sensible implementations in Java.  For large enough values of `unit` you will get a StackOverflowError.  (But that is probably "lesson #2")

Comment: @StephenC True, but you wouldn't write a simple summing using recursion anyway. This is an exercise in recursion, and limits like that is not the point of the exercise.

Comment: @jenkin - Hint: the best solution here is the solution that is easiest to understand.  Which do >>you<< think that is?

Comment: @StephenC  i know i shouldnt use a static field to do this. the question is what's the best achievement about this .

Comment: We can't answer this question because we don't know what your definition of "better" is.  If I had to apply my own definition, I'd say _both_ uses of recursion are terrible, compared to just using a loop.

Comment: @jenkin - I have answered that.  The best solution is the one that is easiest to understand.  **Which do >>you<< think that is?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing static variables is unnecessary, so either solution isn't ideal.

Try thinking like this

1. What are you trying to do? Answer:  `1+...+N`.
2. What is the input? Answer: `N`, the highest number to sum to.
3. What can you do in each step recursively that will help you reach your answer with that input? Answer: Take that number and add it to the result of all `N - 1` solutions.
4. When should you stop recursion and start accumulating the summation results (what's your base case)? Answer: When the number hits 1 (generally, the smallest possible input), or even less than it to prevent a negative number input from causing a StackOverflow error.

> `public static int sumUpTo(int x) {
>     if (x <= 1) return x;
>     return x + sumUpTo(x - 1);
>  }`

Comment: First line can be `if (x == 1) return x;`.

Comment: @shmosel That wouldn't support calling `sumUpTo(0)`. Sure, it can't handle negative values either way, but if a simple `<` will support a `0` parameter for free, I'd say it's the right way to go.